# Inappbrowser not working when submittting form using cordovaInappbrowser

Tags: ionic-framework

When I am using cordovaInappbrowser for submitting form.html form value not change 
when form.html is loaded using inappbrowser. form.html showing default value on form 
is inappbrowser not supported dynamic form submission?

following is my code

```
 $cordovaInAppBrowser.open('templates/payumoneyPaymentForm.html','_blank', options)
            .then(function(event) {
                $scope.payUpaymentForm = $rootScope.paymentDetails;

                prompt("success "+JSON.stringify(event));
            })
            .catch(function(event) {
                prompt("error "+event);
            });

            $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstart', function(e, event){

            });

            $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstop', function(e, event){

              $cordovaInAppBrowser.executeScript({
                        code:"document.getElementById('payUMoneyPaymentFormData').submit();"
                });
            });

            $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loaderror', function(e, event){

                prompt("loaderror");
            });

            $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:exit', function(e, event){

            });

showing blank value in html
following my html page

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="payUMoneyPaymentFormData" name="payuForm" action="https://test.payu.in/_payment" method="POST">
    <!-- BEGIN - Mandatory Config Parameters  -->

    <ion-item>
        <ion-list>
            <input type="text"  id="amount" name="amount"  value="{{payUpaymentForm.amount}}"/>


            <div style="margin-top : 5%;">
                <span>Key*</span><br>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="text" id="key" name="key" maxlength="1000" value="{{payUpaymentForm.key}}" />
                </label>
            </div>
        </ion-list>


        <ion-list>
            <div style="margin-top : 5%;">
                <span>Hash*</span><br>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="hidden" id="hash" name="hash" emaxlength="1000" value="{{payUpaymentForm.hash}}" />
                </label>
            </div>
        </ion-list>

        <ion-list>
            <div style="margin-top : 5%;">
                <span>TxnId*</span><br>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="hidden" name="txnid"  maxlength="1000" value="{{payUpaymentForm.txnid}}" />
                </label>
            </div>
        </ion-list>

        <ion-list>
            <div style="margin-top : 5%;">
                <span>Service Provider*</span><br>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="hidden" id="service_provider" maxlength="1000" name="service_provider"  value="{{payUpaymentForm.service_provider}}" />
                </label>
            </div>
        </ion-list>
        <!-- END - Mandatory Config Parameters  -->

        <!-- BEGIN - Mandatory Parameters-->
        <ion-list>
            <div style="margin-top : 5%;">
                <span>Firstname*</span><br>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="hidden" id="firstname" name="firstname"  value="{{payUpaymentForm.firstname}}" />
                </label>
            </div>
        </ion-list>
        <ion-list>
            <div style="margin-top : 5%;">
                <span>Email*</span><br>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email"  value="{{payUpaymentForm.email}}" />
                </label>
            </div>
        </ion-list>

        <ion-list>
            <div style="margin-top : 5%;">
                <span>productInfo*</span><br>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="hidden" id="productinfo" name="productinfo"  value="{{payUpaymentForm.productinfo}}" />
                </label>
            </div>
        </ion-list>

        <input type="hidden" id="phone" name="phone"  value="{{payUpaymentForm.phone}}" />



        <input type="hidden" name="surl"  value="{{payUpaymentForm.surl}}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="furl"  value="{{payUpaymentForm.furl}}" />
        <!-- END - Mandatory Parameters-->

        <!--BEGIN - Optional Parameters-->
        <input type="hidden" name="address1"  value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="address2"  value="" />
        <input type="hidden"  name="city"  value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="state"  value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="country"  value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="zipcode"  value="" />
        <input type="submit">
    </ion-item>
    <!-- END - Optional Parameters  -->

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill in the dynamic feild values on loadstop or load start event by using Execute Script.

$rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstop', function(e, event){

```
          $cordovaInAppBrowser.executeScript({
                    code:"document.getElementById('service_provider').val('somevalue');document.getElementById('payUMoneyPaymentFormData').submit();"
            });
        });
```